# ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init]; - ERROR

Tags: ios5, alassetlibrary

If I try to run this, I get the error:

"Initializer element is not a compile-time constant."

Can anybody explain to a newly like me why this is happening?

Comment: your code is correct. I think you have written it outside any function.

Comment: you have an example how such a function would look like? and why can I use that only inside a function?

Comment: what I meant is the line of code `ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];` must be in any method and NOT global(outside function so that the `library` variable becomes global)

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct. I think you have written it outside any function.

what I meant is the line of code `ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];` must be in any method and NOT global(outside function so that the library variable becomes global)